# Building libcurl library in c++, Noob Question

Tags: c++, libcurl, building

I wanna write a little c++ program using libcurl. It's for a school project so I need to be able to package everything in a zip file and email it to my instructor.
I've just downloaded the tar from the libcurl website but now I'm not sure what the next step is... What else do I gotta do in order to be able to do `#include "curl/curl.h"` and call curl functions from my main function? Once I do that how would I zip it and make sure my instructor will be able to compile it too? I'm using Ubuntu. Any help will be apprecitated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Download the source from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html).

2) unpack with "tar xvzf tarfilename"

3) cd to newly created directory from the unpack

4) enter "./configure"

5) enter "make" and "make install"

6) write your program and remember to link against the library.

7) When ready to send to prof, I would zip the original libcurl source along with the instructions above and any other you used to get your project to work.

Edit - Something like:

g++ -g -Wall -o myapp  myapp.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lcurl

Comment: Thx a lot! Not sure what to do for step 6... how would I link against the library? Is it in the "g++ -o" command? also, after I do the make install how do I figure out what to put in the #include *** statement?

Comment: Assuming a very simple program just put the include at the top of your source file (or header file if you have one).  For the link use -L<PathToLibrary> and -lcurl toward the end of the g++ command.  If you don't want to install lib in the default path look into the --prefix parameter of configure.  If you do "./configure --help" it explains a little.  Basically you are supplying an alternative directory for make to put the libcurl file.