# Building libcurl library in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, libcurl

I am trying to build libcurl from its source code. I have tried almost everything that has been answered on any forum ever but no success.
Can anyone please tell me how to do it?

I found this question 
[Building libcurl library in c++, Noob Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871563/building-libcurl-library-in-c-noob-question)
 but the solution doesn't work for me

then I found this guide
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/Using-libcurl-with-SSH-support-in-Visual-Studio-2008.pdf
I followed every step, things went smooth until the end of section 3.4 of document, when I try to build libSSH2 it shows error

```
fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libeay32.lib;ssleay32.lib'
```

the possible reasons for this error are that path contains "Spaces" but my path was

```
  C:\openssl_lib\lib
```

as written in the document(without spaces).
When I couldn't find any solution I even renamed the folder

```
"openssl_lib" to "openssllib"
```

just to make sure that "_" character was not the reason for this error but no use.

Then I found that sometimes Linker causes problem if "lib" prefix is not present in names of libraries. I renamed the library files manually to

```
 libeay32.lib and libssleay32.lib
```

but this does not solve the issue either.

I have spent almot 8 hours going through all the trouble again and again , I am too frustrated now so please help...

Environment details:
Windows 7 64-bit
Visual Studio 2008

Comment: Uhm, make sure `libeay32.lib` and `ssleay32.lib` are on the separate lines in the linker config. The error message `cannot open input file 'libeay32.lib;ssleay32.lib'` shows that it's looking for a single file with this weird name.

Comment: you are a life saver @catscradle .
you pointed out the exact problem.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure libeay32.lib and ssleay32.lib are on the separate lines in the linker config. The error message cannot open input file 'libeay32.lib;ssleay32.lib' shows that it's looking for a single file with this weird name.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to build libcurl in future:

Here are links to complete guides on different versions of visual studio.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/Using-libcurl-with-SSH-support-in-Visual-Studio-2008.pdf

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/Using-libcurl-with-SSH-support-in-Visual-Studio-2010.pdf